# Как работает ImmutableList C#

Tags: c#, коллекции

Допустим у нас есть такой код:

```
var builder = ImmutableList.CreateBuilder<string>();
```

Тогда, при добавлении элемента - мы получим совершенно новый объект?

```
builder.Add("1"); тогда получается - это уже другой объект, не тот, что выше
```

```
builder[0] = "1"; снова получаем совершенно новый объект
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не так. Билдер - это не сам лист. Билдер предназначен для того, чтобы немутабельный список построить без дополнительных аллокаций.

Можно считать, что билдер - это обычный `List<T>`.

```cs
ImmutableList<string>.Builder builder = ImmutableList.CreateBuilder<string>();
builder.Add("1"); // это все тот же объект
builder.Add("2"); // это все тот же объект
ImmutableList<string> list1 = builder.ToImmutable(); // а здесь начинается немутабельность

ImmutableList<string> list2 = list1.Add("3");
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(list1, list2));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", list1));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", list2));
```

Вывод в консоль

```
False
1 2
1 2 3
```

---

Можно даже так сделать, и логический смысл не поменяется

```cs
List<string> builder = new List<string>();
builder.Add("1");
builder.Add("2");
ImmutableList<string> list = builder.ToImmutableList();
```

Но технически это не совсем одно и то же, что и билдер. Для немутабельного листа лучше и эффективнее использовать именно `ImmutableList<string>.Builder`.

Comment: Спасибо большое